# How do I output data on new lines with AWK? TSHARK BATCH SCRIPT

Tags: awk, text-processing

I'm trying to live capture packets and output each packets ASCII data on a new line in a text file. I want to be able to still read this file while its being written to. If I can't read it while its being written to. I would like be able to rerun the batch script and have it not overwrite the file and to continue on a new line. My tools are awk tshark batch script I'm open to other options though. So I guess my questions are.

1. How can I output to a text file that I can still read while batch script is still running?
2. If this isn't possible.
   Can I capture one packet at time and rerun a batch script? If so how can I prevent it from overwriting/deleting the previous info from the text file and to continue on a new line.
3. How can I output ASCII data all on one line and start a new line for each packet?

Here is a sample tshark output with this command. Each packet is separated with two newlines. I can also change this with -S

```
tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x
```

```
0000  00 fc 31 55 24 47 a4 72 4d cf 12 f4 06 02 44 00   ..b1...c].....d.
0010  01 23 x5 dt 42 30 63 04 d3 20 c5 24 28 ed 1a 00   .6..@.f... . ...
0020  23 54 cd 32 45 52                                 .3.2..
etc...


0000  00 fc 31 55 24 47 a4 72 4d cf 12 f4 06 02 44 00   ..b1...c].....d.
0010  01 23 x5 dt 42 30 63 04 d3 20 c5 24 28 ed 1a 00   .6..@.f... . ...
0020  23 54 cd 32 45 52                                 .3.2..
etc...
```

Here is another command I'm using.
Some of it has spaces so it was being skipped so I had to add more fields.

```
tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | awk "{print $18, $19, $20}" > "test.txt"
```

Example of output

```
..b1...c].....d.
.6..@.f... . ...
.3.2..


..b1...c].....d.
.6..@.f... . ...
.3.2..
```

This command prints packets ASCII on a single line but continues without creating a new line

```
tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | awk "{printf $18, $19, $20}" > "test.txt"
```

Output continues where it left off

```
..a1...c].....d..6..@.f... . ....3.2....a1...c].....d..6..@.f... . ....3.2....a1...c].....d..6..@.f... . ....3.2..
```

The output I'm looking for is something like this

```
..a1...c].....d..6..@.f........3.2..
..a1...c].....d..6..@.f........3.2..
..a1...c].....d..6..@.f........3.2..
```

Comment: No. There was some Information inside the data that was personal mistakenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```bash
tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | 
awk '
val && !NF{
  print val
  val=""
  next
}
match($0,/(\.+[^.]+\.*)+/){
  val=(val?val OFS:"") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
val && !NF{                  ##Checking if val is NOT NULL and line is empty then do following.
  print val                  ##Printing val here.
  val=""                     ##Nullifying val here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
match($0,/(\.+[^.]+\.*)+/){  ##Using match to match regex (\.+[^.]+\.*)+ here.
  val=(val?val OFS:"") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ##Creating val which has its sub string value and keep appending in it.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block of this awk block here.
  if(val){                   ##Checking if val is NOT NULL then do following.
    print val                ##Printing val here.
  }
}
'
```

Comment: To do this in one-liner form try: `tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | awk 'val && !NF{print val;val="";next} match($0,/(\.+[^.]+\.*)+/){val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} END{if(val){print val}}'`

Comment: I updated my post with a update. If you can take a look I would be very grateful.

Comment: @JimmyJohnson, could you please only update sample of input and expected output in your question(don't put mine or someone else code Just keep yours tried one) and let me know I can take a look to it.

Comment: I have updated two sample inputs I can have.

Comment: @JimmyJohnson, this looks to be very much changed from your initial question. I would like to request you to revert your new changes to old question AND you can ask a new question for your latest edit. changing samples later on will mess up and it will make all answers pointless. So kindly do open a new question for this one.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | awk -f parse.awk
```

Where `parse.awk` is:

```bash
{
   sub(/^[0-9]{4}[ \t]+[0-9a-z \t]+/, "")
   s = (s == "" ? "" : s " ") $0
}
s && !NF {
   print s
   s = ""
}
END {print s}
```

**Output:**

```bash
..a1...c].....d. .6..@.f... . ... .3.2..
..a1...c].....d. .6..@.f... . ... .3.2..
```

Comment: To do that in one line use: `tshark -i 1 -f "CaptureFilter" -x | awk '{sub(/^[0-9]{4}[ \t]+[0-9a-z \t]+/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s " ") $0} s && !NF {print s; s=""} END {print s}'`

Comment: awk: { sub(/^[0-9]{4}[ \t]+[0-9a-z \t]+/, ")
awk:                                                  ^ unterminated string 
I'm getting this error. Its at the " before the )

Comment: There must be a copy/paste error. Make sure you copy command *as is* from here.

Comment: I am using windows. I must not have something installed correctly or its a linux to windows error. I have to change the beginning ' with a "

Comment: No, don't change from `'` to `"`  otherwise command will break. Even on Windows my suggested awk should work

Comment: awk: '{sub(/[0-9]{4}[
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248748/discussion-between-jimmyjohnson-and-anubhava).

Comment: Here is a working demo: https://ideone.com/tKEFgg

Comment: Standard advice for running awk on Windows is to save the script in a file, e.g. named `script`, then run it as `awk -f script` instead of `awk '...'` to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules.

Comment: @JimmyJohnson: You can try my updated answer now